# Laravel 5.4 redirect taking method from request object

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers, laravel-5.4, http-redirect

Recently I have started a Laravel 5.4 project and I found something I don't quite understand and I'm posting this question hoping to solve this issue and find out if it's expected behaviour or a bug.

The thing is, I'm submitting an update form which looks like so:

```
<form id="post-form" action="{{url('admin/posts/'.$post->id)}}" method="POST">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{ method_field('PUT') }}
  <!-- Some fields -->
</form>
```

And I try to validate that request on the controller method:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        // Fields to validate
    ]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
   return back()
   ->withErrors($validator)
   ->withInput();
}
```

My problem comes when the validation fails and the redirect is performed, because I get a code **405** error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

Indeed, the url is correct but the method is wrong, as shown in the HTTP headers:

```
Request URL:https://myproject.dev/admin/posts/1/edit
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:405 
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

It should be a GET instead of a PUT. My best guess is that is using the _method property of the `$request` object to redirect, instead of using the GET method.

A `dump($request->all())` right before the redirect call:

```
array:19 [
  "_token" => "XOtwEeXwgnuc8fNqCwxkdO992bU6FObDwTuCg1cJ"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  //fields
]
```

Some things I have already tried with no luck:

- Unsetting the _method from the request: `unset($request['_method'])`
- Name the route and redirect based in that name:

  ```
  // The routes file (routes/web.php)
  Route::get('posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit')->name('edit-post');

  // The redirect (controller)
  return redirect()->route('edit-post', ['id' => 1])
      ->withErrors($validator)
      ->withInput();
  ```
- Specify the url in the redirect

  ```
  // The redirect (controller)
  return redirect('admin/posts/'.$post->id.'/edit')
      ->withErrors($validator)
      ->withInput();
  ```

So how could I perform that redirect with a normal GET method? Is this an expected behaviour? Thank you in advance, any advice or hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate put route in your `routes.php` file.

```
Route::get('posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit')->name('edit-post');
Route::put('posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit')->name('edit-post');
```

The `get` function means this route will handle routes using the GET method. You need to add a `put` to handle requests using the PUT method. All available route methods are available in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing).

---

You can also use the match function to match multiple methods in one line. Like so:

```
Route::match(['get', 'put'], 'posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');
```

Comment: So it is an expected behaviour to perform the redirect using the method present in the request object?